# Crop Stage/Layer before stage.toDataURL() in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, kineticjs

Using `stage.toDataURL()` in KineticJS, a JPEG image can be generated.

**Problem:** The generated image has to be cropped into a smaller image and saved onto the web server. Is there a way to crop the stage so that the data uri created by `stage.toDataURL()` is the final cropped image? Or do I have to crop it on the server side?

Comment: I'm not familiar with kineticjs but can you create another offscreen canvas to do the cropping, then draw the main canvas on to that? I'll look at KineticJS real quick.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea! On another canvas, probably load the image into a KineticJS `Image` object and use its cropping function, and `.toDataURL()` to generate the cropped version.

Comment: Read through a small amount of the documentation but it sounds like that should work. Interested in the outcome.

Comment: Yup your suggestion works :)

Comment: If you add your suggested solution as an answer, I'll select it as the best answer

Comment: Posted it as an answer, if you want to edit in your kinetic js specific approach that might be helpful for people who google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another offscreen canvas that will be used for the cropping. Then draw the main canvas to that cropping canvas and crop as necessary before calling toDataURL.

Comment: Any sample code to help. I seem to run through the same problem